How to format input number while editing in ASP.NET Core?
This is my code:
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalBudget, new { @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TotalBudget, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

It makes an input of number type without formatting.
I want to format input value while editing.
The format that I want is
$###,###,###.##

Examples: $22,123.00, $3,000,000.12
I've tried:
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalBudget, new { @class = "form-control", @format= "${###,###,###,###.##}" }) //@format= "{0:C2}"
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TotalBudget, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{$###,###,###,###.##}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

What did I do wrong?

You Could try JavaScript code to implement your requirement. Below is sample code which will allow you to format the field at editing time with currency.
Index.cshtml:
@model WebApplication1.Models.BudgetViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Budget Form";
}

<h2>Enter Budget</h2>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalBudget, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "totalBudget" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TotalBudget, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#totalBudget').on('input', function () {
            // Remove any characters that are not numbers, periods, or commas
            var value = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

            // Format the value
            var formattedValue = formatCurrency(value);

            // Set the formatted value back to the input field
            $(this).val(formattedValue);
        });
    });

    function formatCurrency(value) {
        // Split the value into integer and decimal parts
        var parts = value.split('.');
        var integerPart = parts[0];
        var decimalPart = parts[1] ? '.' + parts[1].slice(0, 2) : '';

        // Format the integer part with commas
        var formattedInteger = integerPart.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');

        // Handle cases when the user enters just the decimal point or a number like "0."
        if (value.endsWith('.')) {
            decimalPart = '.';
        }

        // Return the formatted value with a dollar sign
        return '$' + formattedInteger + decimalPart;
    }
</script>

BudgetViewModel.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class BudgetViewModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]

        public decimal TotalBudget { get; set; }

    }
}


